# How to set a cookie in client browser in NextJS 14?

Tags: javascript, next.js, cookies

## I tried to save cookie in my client browser using nextjs 14 app router in API folder but didn't work

**Here is the code**

**app/api/auth/login/route.js**

```
const { NextResponse } = require("next/server");
import connect from "@/app/lib/mongodb";
import MemberModel from "@/app/models/Member.model";
import Notifications from "@/app/models/Notifications";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");


export async function POST(req) {
    const data = await req.json()
    await connect()
    let userdata = await MemberModel.find({
        email: data.email
    })
    if (userdata.length === 0) {
        return NextResponse.json({ uid: false })
    }
    if ((userdata[0].email === data.email) && ((CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(userdata[0].password, process.env.CRYPTO_SECRET_KEY).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)) === data.password)) {
        const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        cookies().set('email', (CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(userdata[0].password, process.env.CRYPTO_SECRET_KEY).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)), { expires: Date.now() + oneDay })
        await Notifications.create({
            msg: `User login with email : ${userdata[0].email}`
        })
        return NextResponse.json({ uid: true })
    } else {
        return NextResponse.json({ uid: false })
    }
}
```

Comment: plz try this https://maxschmitt.me/posts/next-js-cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Expected Output :**

> Set cookie at client

**Cause :**

> Your response, doesn't contains a `Set-Cookie` header

**Solution:**

Change your code from :

```
return NextResponse.json({ uid: true })
```

to

```
return NextResponse.json(
    { uid: true },
    { headers: { 'Set-Cookie': `COOKIE_VALUE` } },
);
```

***Please, Read :***

- Cookies : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#cookies
- NextResponse : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response

***Read the below links to understand syntax, optional parameters etc. :***

- Response : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response
- Response: json() static method : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json_static#syntax

> If you still have any doubts, leave comments.